# MySql query is taking more than 60s to execute. How to improve performance

Tags: mysql

I have written a query to select all rows where value of a column 'gvA' in previous row is 0 and non-zero in current row. But my issue is this query takes too long to execute.
My table has 40000 rows and query takes about 60-65 seconds which is too much for a query. How can I improve query for better performance.Following is my query

```
SELECT device_no,datetime 
FROM (
  SELECT
    gvA,
    (SELECT e2.gvA
     FROM tyn_records e2
     WHERE e2.tyn_id < e1.tyn_id
     ORDER BY tyn_id DESC LIMIT 1) as previous_value,
    datetime,
    device_no
  FROM tyn_records e1
  WHERE gvA > 0 AND DATE(datetime) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
) selected
WHERE selected.previous_value = 0
```

Following are my tables
Devices:

[image: Following is devices table]

tyn_records:

[image: tyn_records table]

Comment: Pls include the results of the explain and list all indexes you have on the tyn_records table.

Comment: are all your date fields date only and not date/time?  In other words, do your columns contain actual time components too.  You are also referring to a device in outermost result, but no context of device internally -- unless the gvA IS the device you are referencing.

Comment: I have added images of tables , hope you get the required info from them

Answer (score 0):

I would do two things:

1. I would rephrase the query a bit, specifically to remove the `DATE()` function in the left side of the filtering condition.

   ```
   select
     device_no,
     datetime 
   from (
     select
       gva, 
       lag(gva) over(order by tyn_id) as previous_value,
       datetime,
       device_no
     from tyn_records
     where gva > 0 
       and datetime between curdate() - interval 2 day
                        and curdate() - interval 1 day
   ) x
   where previous_value = 0
   ```
2. With the function on the left side of the predicate removed, you can create an index suitable to optimize the query:

   ```
   create index ix1 on tyn_records (datetime, gva);
   ```

As a side note, the way you compute `previous_value` may not be deterministic, and could produce different results each time you run the query. This may happen if the column `tyn_id` is non unique.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by tyn_id) as 'previous_value',
    datetime,
    device_no
  from tyn' at line 7

Comment: @ZeeshanCh If you are getting that error, then maybe you have an older version of MySQL (older than 8.x). If that's the case, then replace the `lag(gva) over(order by tyn_id)` part by the subquery you had in your answer.